# Conflicting docker IP in elastic beanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I have a elastic beanstalk app which is running on the docker platform.

I am trying to connect to a private IP (172.17.57.52) which is in conflict with the docker bridge IP range.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-18-1-22 ~]$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.18.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.169.254 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.18.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I've gone through the documentation for Dockerrun.aws.json and there currently there is no provision to configure the network manually.

Is there a way to manually configure the docker IP range in elasticbean stalk?

I've gone through the documentation for Dockerrun.aws.json and there currently there is no provision to configure the network manually.